How to develop with layer 2
I'm am very new on Ethereum, I'm learning solidity, I have a question, how to develop layer 2 like arbitrum, optimism or zksync on solidity or another programming language?

It depends.
Different Layer 2 blockchains utilize different technologies. Some of them are (somewhat) EVM compatible, which means you can use (almost) regular Solidity. But some of them are not EVM compatible, and you have to use different languages.
I suggest you choose whether you want to write in Solidity or not, and then choose the L2 you want to utilize. Or, if in doubt, just forget about L2s for now and focus on just writing Solidity for L1. That's the most straightforward route.

To develop a Layer 2 (L2) solution like Arbitrum, Optimism, or zkSync, you would need to:
Choose the Rollup Type:
Optimistic Rollups (e.g., Arbitrum, Optimism) rely on fraud proofs to verify transactions.
zk-Rollups (e.g., zkSync) use zero-knowledge proofs (zk-SNARKs or zk-STARKs) for transaction validation.
Develop Smart Contracts: Write Solidity contracts for both Ethereum (L1) and the L2 network. These handle transactions, token transfers, and bridge interactions.
Implement Transaction Aggregation: Batch multiple transactions off-chain and submit them to Ethereum for final settlement.
Set Up a Bridge: Implement a bridge to transfer assets between Ethereum and your L2 network.
Scaling Mechanism: Use fraud proofs (for Optimistic Rollups) or zk-proofs (for zk-Rollups) to ensure transaction validity.
For Arbitrum or Optimism, Solidity is enough, while zkSync and StarkNet may require additional knowledge (e.g., Cairo for StarkNet).
